# Historical Variance Decomposition of Linear regressions

Tags: python, r, linear-regression, decomposition

Suppose that I have fitted a linear regression model that takes the following general form:

[image]

where `Y` is my target, `i = {1, ...n}` is the number of explanatory variables `Xs` and `t`, is indexing time. So, is time series. `beta` is the coefficient of the estimated equation.

I want to do a Historical Variance decomposition to understand the contribution of each X on the evolution of y

For example like this: https://medium.com/bonothesauro/deficits-are-raising-interest-rates-but-other-factors-are-lowering-them-6d1e68776b7a

[image]

Can someone help me implement this in R or Python ? So, far I found no source only for [VAR models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806668/historical-variance-error-decomposition-plot-in-r). But I am interested in more simpler linear regressions.