# How to manually conduct a historical decomposition of shocks from an SVAR Model in R

Tags: r, variables, time-series

I have the following xts dataset in R, which I'm using to build an SVAR model.

```
data <- structure(c(1.54054238132604, 5.22775636647117, 1.75154671443607, 
-4.00396437623925, -4.99849595390862, -3.58991362838901, -2.08646214793927, 
4.38408682550573, -1.32609419137286, -10.0477865139619, -10.5789067079456, 
3.53586648125426, 3.80285045230506, 4.54214390385599, 5.25998848716807, 
4.53265591355598, 4.18968593558051, 3.53167443997122, 2.68286514861102, 
2.28625948262682, 1.9539414753903, 2.30401026783675), .Dim = c(11L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("GDP", "CPI")), index = structure(c(1514764800, 
1522540800, 1530403200, 1538352000, 1546300800, 1554076800, 1561939200, 
1569888000, 1577836800, 1585699200, 1593561600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

Here is the code for my model.

```
library(vars)

var.model <- vars::VAR(data, p=1, type = 'cons')
svar.model <- vars::BQ(var.model)
```

I'm looking to replicate [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421994/12388534) by running a historical decomposition on my SVAR model. The function in this example is for a VAR model and I'm looking for advice on how to amend this function for it to work on my SVAR model. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to explore how `svars` functions are implemented in source code to get ideas for what you want to accomplish. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226817 for tips on looking under-the-hood.

Comment: Thanks @SEAnalyst, I'm looking at the source code now and a bit unsure on how to apply it to my example. So I'll edit my post with the source code in case anyone has an idea on how to approach it

Comment: This might be useful :https://rdrr.io/cran/svars/man/hd.html

Comment: Thanks @Waldi , I know about this function however it only works on SVAR objects from the ```svars``` package and not the ```vars``` one, so I'm trying to figure out a way to do it manually in my case

Comment: @Tanga94 have you tried reading https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svars/vignettes/svars.pdf ? On page 14 there is a table describing how the creators structured the process to identify shocks/breaks there;

Comment: Thanks @DiegoQueiroz, realised it might be a simpler solution to just run this in EViews and export the results to R